# Efficient Options to do Stream Joins(with Large Time gaps)

Tags: stream-processing, apache-kafka

Use Case: I need to join two stream sources(say `orders(order_id, order_val)` and `shipments(shipment_id, shipment_val)`) based on an id(`order_id = shipment_id`) and generate a new event `shipment_order(id, order_val, shipment_val)`

Note that the gap between events might be huge(1 year - 2 years)
Ex: `order(order_id = 1, value=1)` might arrive today but the `shipment(shipment_id=1, value=2)` might arrive after an year.

I am exploring patterns to achieve such long window efficient stream joins:

1. Store Events on DynamoDB(or any other Data Store) and re-emit events through DynamoDB Streams(Change Data capture in general), when either a order DDB event or shipment DDB event arrives, I check DynamoDB for both events using the DDB event id and perform a join and emit a new shipment_order
2. Using Kafka Stream joins with large windows(2 years)

Questions:

1. what are some good patterns to achieve such large window joins(Am I on the right track by considering the above options?)
2. Is doing a 2-year window join recommended in Stateful systems such as Kafka? (what are the implications?)

Note: Assume that the system processes about 200 Million events a day with spikes. By Efficiency, I mean general time/cost efficiency(and trade-offs).

Comment: I think this is inherently a bad idea. You need to hold in memory all the objects while you wait for a stream match and you get 200M orders a day. You might as well use a standard database

Comment: @Ewan Could you elaborate on what you mean by a standard database? (is it different from the DynamoDB approach I mentioned?). Any resources would be appreciated. Thanks